# Error while inserting data while using openrowset

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, db2

I am trying to insert data into db2 table using openrowset. I have a csv file located at a particular location which I am trying to read using openrowset. Following is the code:

```
using (OdbcConnection connection =
                           new OdbcConnection("DSN=DBHUBD"))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("insert into trgisl.LCR_HQLA_WEIGHT  select * from OPENROWSET   ( 'MSDAQL','Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; " +
                                   "ColNameHeader = TRUE; Format = CSVDelimited; ''','select * from " + csvPath + "')", connection))
                { 

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

However when I try and debug i get following error:

> ERROR [42601] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected
>   token "OPENROWSET" was found following "EIGHT  select * from". 
>   Expected tokens may include:  "UNNEST".  SQLSTATE=42601

My initial thought was some library/reference issue. also added microsoft excel 14.0 object library into reference of the project, but still getting the same error. I wonder if there is any other syntax for openrowset

Answer (score 0):

Db2 rejects your syntax because Db2 does not recognize the opwnrowset token - it's not valid syntax for Db2.

If your aim is to add bulk data from a CSV file into a Db2 table using c# then try using the Db2BulkCopy class supplied by the IBM Data Server Provider for .net.

See example [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2BulkCopyClass.html).